# Pandas Rolling Filter

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

I have a `df` that looks like this for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Change': [-0.5, -0.25, 1, 1.5, 0.25,-0.75, -1, 2, .... })
```

What I'm looking to do is to filter this `df['Change']` column for above and below 0, calculate the mean for both, and then add the two results together. But I want to be able to do this on a rolling basis over a window of 100.

I can do this in a very blunt way by just looping through the `df` as I do in the below:

```
df['diff'] = np.NAN
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if i > 100:
        X = df.iloc[i - 100:i]
        ups = X[X['change'] > 0]['change'].mean()
        downs = X[X['change'] < 0]['change'].mean()
        df['diff'].iloc[i] = (ups + downs)
```

However, it's quite slow and was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.rolling(window=100).apply(foo)`
where `foo` is your function.
for example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import monotonic

df = pd.DataFrame({'Change': np.random.randint(-5, 5, size=(10000,))})

def foo(x):
    ups = x[x > 0].mean()
    downs = x[x < 0].mean()
    return ups + downs


start = monotonic()
res = df.Change.rolling(100).apply(foo)
print(f'time took: {monotonic() - start:.3f} s.')
```

```
Out:
    time took: 2.544 s.
```

With `raw=True` keyword argument it will be faster

```py
start = monotonic()
res = df.Change.rolling(100).apply(foo, raw=True)
print(f'with raw=True time took: {monotonic() - start:.3f} s.')
```

```
Out:
     with raw=True time took: 0.107 s.
```

Also yoy can parallelize `apply` method with [parallel-pandas](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-pandas/) library.
It's very simple:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import monotonic
from parallel_pandas import ParallelPandas

ParallelPandas.initialize(n_cpu=8, disable_pr_bar=True)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Change': np.random.randint(-5, 5, size=(10000,))})


def foo(x):
    ups = x[x > 0].mean()
    downs = x[x < 0].mean()
    return ups + downs
#p_apply - is parallel analogue of apply method
start = monotonic()
res = df.Change.rolling(100).p_apply(foo, raw=True)
print(f'parallel with raw=True time took: {monotonic() - start:.3f} s.')
```

```
Out:
    parallel with raw=True time took: 0.047 s.
```

Total speedup is `2.5 / 0.05 = 50`!